# Hidden network after cloning Red Hat

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat

I have a bizarre network problem with Red Hat. I have a virtual RHEL6 guest machine running on a ESXi 5.5 hypervisor. The VM is a clone of a base 'template' I created.

The problem is there seems to be a hidden network interface that grabs a specific IP address each time the template is deployed. This IP address is already assigned another machine on the network which is outside the DHCP pool. Subsequently I'm then unable to access the existing machine until I disable the network on the newly built guest.

Running ifconfig -a shows only the correctly assigned dhcp address to a single interface. Before creating the template I removed the network config scripts and the /etc/udev/rules.d/70-* files but I'm thinking something else has probably been left behind.

Is there anyway to track down this mystery interface?

Comment: On your new deployed VM. check the output of `ip addr show` this will show if there are 2 or more IP's on a single interface

Comment: Thanks. So running an `ip addr show` shows the extra IP address on the interface. What I now need to know is how it's getting there. The interface is booting to dhcp so I'm not sure how it could be obtaining an additional IP.

Comment: The secondary IP's in `ip addr show` are usually static placed the `ip addr add` command. That ip might be in your original image. Try using `ip addr flush dev eth0` to remove all of the ips from your base image and clone the new image. See if that will help with your issue